# Possible to backup/restore simultaneously with Ubuntu 22.04 on a LAN/cross-over cable?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, restore, ubuntu-22.04

I have several identical Dell laptops that came pre-installed with Ubuntu 22.04.  I need to set these up for a classroom environment with a VMware guest operating system (Solaris).  I managed to get one of them running correctly after a couple weeks, but do not remember all the steps taken to get there, and now cannot duplicate the results on the rest.  It occurred to me that a backup of the configured machine restored to the others would likely work.  Does not have to be done across a crossover LAN cable; this would just avoid the need for a storage media.  Avoiding the need for a Live boot media would be good too, if possible.

Ideas?

Comment: so you can't just stream the contents of laptop A's system disk to laptop B without other software/infrastructure. in particular both systems need to be offline to take/apply the image, and some software is required to facilitate that interaction.  you may be able to find a software with live boot media you can use with PXE to do that, but you won't be able to do it while either system is booted off its local disks.

Answer (score 0):

Several methods are given in the Ask Ubuntu article
[How to copy an Ubuntu install from one laptop to another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another).

In general, the proposed methods are :

- Copy `/home/[username]` for user settings
- Copy installed packages using Synaptics : On the source computer
  menu *File > Save markings* with "Save full state, not only changes",
  and on the other computer *File > Read markings*
- [Using disk images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62340/how-to-copy-an-ubuntu-install-from-one-laptop-to-another/62383#62383).